# Credit card validation and parsing utilities for .Net Compact framework 3.5

Tags: .net, compact-framework, credit-card

I have payment gateway integration in my application developed using .Net Compact framework 3.5.

Is there any "Credit card validation and parsing utilities" that i can use in my application or is there any class that i can use to identify the type of the card?

Answer (score 3):

Google for Lunn or Luhn validation. This will simply validate that the cc number is a valid sequence, but you will need to obviously validate that against the provider.

The same links may provide you with the prefixes used by several card companies.

Comment: For more googling the prefix lists are called "BIN lists" (bank id number)

Answer (score 0):

Try Subsonic.Sugar .. then you could do somethign like this

```
 protected void ValidateCardServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
```

{
    bool cardValidate;
    string item = ddlCardType.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper();

```
if (item == "MASTERCARD")
  cardValidate = SubSonic.Sugar.Validation.IsCreditCardMasterCard(args.Value);
else if (item == "VISA")
  cardValidate = SubSonic.Sugar.Validation.IsCreditCardVisa(args.Value);
else if (item == "ACME")
  cardValidate = SubSonic.Sugar.Validation.IsCreditCardDinersClub(args.Value);
else if (item == "DINERS")
  cardValidate = SubSonic.Sugar.Validation.IsCreditCardAmericanExpress(args.Value);
else
  cardValidate = SubSonic.Sugar.Validation.IsCreditCardAny(args.Value);

args.IsValid = cardValidate;
```

}